# Grabbing a JSON object by name

Tags: json

I have a json object with the following structure:

```
[
{
"filters": [
    {
        "name": "category",
        "list": [
            {
                "category-abc": {
                    "title": "abc",
                    "number": "2"
                }
            },
            {
                "category-def": {
                    "title": "def",
                    "number": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "topic",
        "list": [
            {
                "topic-abc": {
                    "title": "abc",
                    "number": "6"
                }
            },
            {
                "topic-def": {
                    "title": "def",
                    "number": "5"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
]
```

The list is actually much longer, with many name | list pairs. I am looking to grab each list as I iterate along an array of list names, but don't want to walk that list every time, so I want to grab the list by name.

Something like this:

```
filters['topic'][0].title
```

But that won't work, as there's the "name" key there. Is there any way to do this without conditionals?

Comment: why don't you parse JSON first and then iterate ?

Comment: @Reflective It looks like he already parsed it, that's why he has an array, not a string.

Comment: I don't think you can do it without a loop and conditionals. If you wanted to be able to get the "topic" element directly, you should have made that a key rather than a value.

Comment: It is hitting this particular function as an object. I suppose I'm trying to just cherry pick what I want from the object rather than go through it each time looking for the cherry. Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology...

Comment: @Barmar - that's exactly what I'm afraid of...

Comment: But you don't have to do it every time. You can do it once and save references to the subobjects in variables.

Comment: ok - let me try that. good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want (it assumes `data` contains the original JSON object):

```
var filters = [];
foreach (var subitem in data[0].filters) {
  filters[subitem.name] = subitem.list;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, but there is one requirement: the name should be unique. This is not specified in the question.

Comment: This assumes the name is unique. If there are duplicates, it will use the last one.

Comment: if not unique could be like that `if (!filters[subitem.name]) filters[subitem.name] = []; filters[subitem.name].push(subitem.list);`

Comment: But then she'll have to do another level of iteration to use those values, which it doesn't look like she wants.